# Get name of node in Kendo UI Multiple Select when you click

Tags: kendo-ui, multiple-select

I am using the Kendo UI multiple select, and I want the name of the node which is currently selected when you click on it. This is not just when I click on `X` to remove the node, although I also want the name when I remove it.

In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/mitesh_inf/9WfGA/6/), when I click on the tags, I want the names such as "Europe" and "Africa".

I have tried this code, but it works only sometimes, and not when I click on `X`.

```
    $('.k-multiselect-wrap li .k-delete').click(function() {
           console.log('Select to remove it');          
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/) because the items are being added to the DOM after your initial binding, so regular `.click` event bindings won't work for any elements added in the future. For example:

```
$(document).on("click", "li.k-button span.k-icon.k-delete", function () {
    console.log("Clicked on X: " + $(this).siblings().first().text());
});
```

See  [update jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7XMFS/)

Comment: Avoid using `$(document).on(...)` if you have a more narrow scope available. If you attach it to `document` then it will fire for every element on your page, and then check if it meets your filter, which can impact performance.